# "Conceal Carry" vs. "Concealed Carry"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrases

I have been doing some research on firearms law lately, and have run across a lot of people using the phrase "conceal carry" to describe people carrying a concealed firearm. In my opinion, this should be "*concealed* carry", since if asked the question "how are you carrying your firearm?" I would reply, "I'm carrying it in a concealed fashion," not "I'm carrying it in a conceal fashion."

Still, am I wrong? Would it be equally correct to use the phrase "conceal carry" in some circumstances?

Comment: You are right.  There are many examples of this. Using "concealed" carry shouldn't cause any issues... People get along fine saying both "ice tea" and "iced tea".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. "Conceal carry" is simple verbal laziness, along the lines of dropping the "g" in the "ing" suffix. It is also (for now) a purely verbal phenomenon
[image]

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conceal+carry%2C+concealed+carry&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconcealed%20carry%3B%2Cc0

since the ngram shows no instances of "conceal carry" at all.

But rest assured that it's only a matter of time.

Comment: If he's been doing "research" that sounds like he's finding the term in written text (possibly forums?). It's not completely clear that he's hearing it spoken that way.

Comment: I wouldn't be too sure about that "only a matter of time". As [this NGrams shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drink-drive+laws%2Cdrink+drive+laws%2Cdrink+driving+laws%2Cdrink-driving+laws&year_start=1980&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrink%20-%20drive%20laws%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrink%20driving%20laws%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrink%20-%20driving%20laws%3B%2Cc0), the similar "lazy, ungrammatical" usage ***drink drive laws*** got off to a good start, but we've increasingly standardised on the somewhat more grammatical ***drink-driving laws***.

Comment: If people are saying it, sooner or later they'll be writing it. And Catija may well be right, in which case "a matter of time" means right now.

Comment: See, e.g., http://www.thetruthaboutguns.com/2015/05/jon-wayne-taylor/gear-review-neomag-magazine-pocket-clips/.

Comment: And also:

 http://www.gandermountain.com/help-center/conceal-carry-policy.shtml

and:

http://www.ok.gov/osbi/Handgun_Licensing/Check_the_Status_of_Your_Application/